# Optimize A Complex Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The below procedure taking 9 seconds to execute, and the primary table has only 30000 records.

```
   ALTER PROC [dbo].[TransactionReport_NewWork] @StartDate datetime = NULL, @EndDate datetime = NULL
, @Mid varchar(50) = NULL -- varchar(5000)=null                                            
, @BatchNo varchar(50) = NULL,
@AuthId varchar(50) = NULL, @RRN varchar(50) = NULL   --varchar(500)=null                                                                      
, @CardNo varchar(50) = NULL, @PageNo int = NULL, @PageSize int = 10, @ReportType int = NULL, @ReportSubType int = NULL,
@IsOrder varchar(10) = NULL,
@CurrencyCode varchar(10) = NULL
, @InvoiceNo varchar(50) = NULL
, @AppCode varchar(5) = NULL
, @ProductCodes StringValues READONLY,   --varchar(10)=null,                            
@TIDS StringValues READONLY
, @SettlementStatus IntegerValues READONLY --  varchar(50)=null                                            
, @TransactionType IntegerValues READONLY
, @ReportValues StringValues READONLY
AS


  SET @PageNo = (CASE
    WHEN @PageNo = 0 THEN 1
    WHEN @PageNo IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE @PageNo
  END)


  SET @PageSize = (CASE
    WHEN @PageSize = 0 THEN 2147483647
    ELSE @PageSize
  END)

  SELECT
    x.*  --into #TransLogDetail

  FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    --order by a.TransactionDateTime desc          
    ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN j.ProductName IS NOT NULL THEN j.ProductCode
    END ASC,
    CASE
      WHEN j.ProductName IS NULL THEN a.TransactionDateTime
    END DESC,
    a.TransactionDateTime DESC
    ) SNo,
    b.MerchantName,
    a.var64_42 MID,
    a.var64_41 TID,
    (CASE
      WHEN c.TransactionType = 'SALE' THEN d.TransactionStatus
      WHEN c.TransactionType = 'MOTO' THEN 'MOTO'
      --when c.TransactionType ='LOYALTY_POINTS_REDEMPTION' then c.TransactionType          
      ELSE d.TransactionStatus
    END)
    AS TransactionType,
    a.var64_60 BatchNo,
    (CASE
      WHEN
        a.var64_54 IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(CONVERT(decimal, a.var64_04) / 100 AS numeric(18, 2)) - CAST(ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal, a.var64_54) / 100, 0) AS numeric(18, 2))
      ELSE CAST(CONVERT(decimal, a.var64_04) / 100 AS numeric(18, 2))
    END) Amount,
    (CASE
      WHEN c.TransactionType = 'MOTO' THEN SUBSTRING(a.var64_02, 1, 6) + '******' + SUBSTRING(a.var64_02, 13, 4)
      ELSE
        --substring(a.var64_35,1,6) +'******'+  substring(a.var64_35,13,4)                                   
        SUBSTRING(a.var64_02, 1, 6) + '******' + SUBSTRING(a.var64_02, 13, 4)

    END)
    CardNumber,
    a.var64_38 AuthID,
    a.var64_37 RRN,
    a.var64_62 InvoiceNo,
    CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(STUFF((CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())) + a.var64_13 + ' ' + a.var64_12), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':'))
    TransactionDateTime,
    e.SettlementStatus,
    a.var64_35 Track2,
    a.var64_11 Stan,
    h.Description AS POSEntryMode,
    g.Description AS POSConditionCode,
    (CASE
      WHEN a.var64_54 IS NULL THEN NULL
      ELSE CAST(ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal, a.var64_54) / 100, 0) AS numeric(18, 2))
    END) Tip,
    a.var64_55 BatchData,
    a.OrderNo,
    a.var64_48 KSN
    --, convert(varchar,a.TransactionDateTime,120) TransactionDateTime_Web                                  
    ,
    STUFF(STUFF((CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())) + a.var64_13 + ' ' + a.var64_12), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':') TransactionDateTime_Web
    --, isnull( i.Code +'('+isnull(i.Symbol,'')+')', N'PKR(?)') as CurrencyCode                            
    ,
    ISNULL(i.Code, 'PKR') AS CurrencyCode,
    a.var64_02 Pan,
    j.ProductName,
    (CASE
      WHEN a.var64_28 = '' THEN 0
      ELSE CAST(ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal, a.var64_28) / 100, 0) AS numeric(18, 2))
    END) AS ProductPrice,
    (CASE
      WHEN a.var64_28 = '' THEN 0
      ELSE CAST(ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal, RIGHT(a.var64_61, 12)) / 100, 0) AS numeric(18, 2))
    END) ProductQuantity,
    --a.var64_28 as  ProductPrice                      
    --,a.var64_61 as ProductQuantity,               
    (CASE
      WHEN LEN(a.var64_63) >= 57 THEN CAST(ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal, SUBSTRING(a.var64_63, 1, 12)) / 100, 0) AS numeric(18, 2)) +
        CAST(ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal, SUBSTRING(a.var64_63, 43, 12)) / 100, 0) AS numeric(18, 2))
      ELSE 0
    END) TotalDiscount,
    TotalRecords = COUNT(*) OVER (),
    TotalPages = CAST(CEILING(COUNT(*) OVER () / (@PageSize * 1.0)) AS int)
  --substring(a.var64_63,1,12)+'Part2'+substring(a.var64_63,43,12) TotalDiscount              

  FROM TransactionResponseLog a
  LEFT JOIN Merchant b
    ON a.var64_42 = b.mid
    AND b.isactive = 1
  LEFT JOIN GatewayTransactionType c
    ON a.TransactionTypeID = c.TransactionTypeID
  LEFT JOIN TransactionStatus d
    ON a.TransactionStatusID = d.TransactionStatusId
  LEFT JOIN SettlementStatus e
    ON a.SettlementStatusID = e.SettlementStatusId
  LEFT JOIN Association f
    ON
    --substring(a.var64_35,1,1)                               
    SUBSTRING(a.var64_02, 1, 1)
    = f.PaymentAssocationCode
  LEFT JOIN POSConditionCode g
    ON a.var64_25 = g.Code
  LEFT JOIN POSEntryMode h
    ON a.var64_22 = h.Code
  LEFT JOIN CurrencyCode i
    ON i.IsoCode = ISNULL(a.var64_49, '0586')
  LEFT JOIN ProuctWithRequestId j
    ON a.TransRequestID = j.TransRequestID

  WHERE a.var64_42 = ISNULL(@MID, a.var64_42)

  --and   a.var64_49 =isnull(@CurrencyCode,a.var64_49)                            

  AND
  (
  -------------For  Currency Check                           

  ------- For Currency  Check Is Not Null                                  
  ((
  --a.var64_49 =@CurrencyCode                           
  i.IsoCode = @CurrencyCode
  )
  AND (@CurrencyCode IS NOT NULL))

  OR
  ----For All Transactions                                              
  ((@CurrencyCode IS NULL)
  AND (1 = 1))
  )

  AND (
  -------------For  InvoiceNo Check                           
  --select * from TerminalSequence             
  ------- For InvoiceNo  Check Is Not Null                                  
  ((a.var64_62 = @InvoiceNo)
  AND (@InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL)
  AND a.var64_60 = (SELECT
    dbo.fn_LPAD(a.BatchNo, 6, '0')
  FROM TerminalSequence a
  WHERE a.TID IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ReportValues)
  AND a.AppCode = @AppCode)


  )

  OR
  ----For All Transactions                                              
  ((@InvoiceNo IS NULL)
  )
  )

  AND (
  ((j.ProductCode IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ProductCodes)
  )
  AND (@ProductCodesCount <> 0))
  OR ((@ProductCodesCount = 0))
  )


  AND (
  ((a.var64_41 IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @TIDS)
  )
  AND (@TIdCount <> 0))
  OR ((a.var64_41 = a.var64_41)
  AND (@TIdCount = 0))
  )

  AND (
  ------- For Gateway  Transactions Other Than Moto                                        
  ((@TranTypeExMotoCount <> 0)
  AND (a.TransactionStatusId IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @TransactionTypeExMoto)
  )
  AND (a.TransactionTypeId <> @MotoId-- (  select * from @TransactionTypeMoto   )                                         
  )
  )

  OR
  ------- For Gateway Moto Transaction                                        
  ((@TranTypeMotoCount <> 0)
  AND (a.TransactionTypeId = @MotoId))
  --- For All Transactions                                          
  OR
  ((a.TransactionStatusId = a.TransactionStatusId)
  AND (@TranTypeCount = 0))

  )

  AND CONVERT(date, a.TransactionDateTime) BETWEEN ISNULL(CONVERT(date, @StartDate), a.TransactionDateTime)
  AND ISNULL(CONVERT(date, @EndDate), a.TransactionDateTime)
  AND (
  ((a.SettlementStatusId IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @SettlementStatus)
  )
  AND (@SettlementStatusCount <> 0))
  OR ((a.SettlementStatusId = a.SettlementStatusId)
  AND (@SettlementStatusCount = 0))
  )

  AND a.var64_38 = ISNULL(@AuthID, a.var64_38)
  AND a.var64_37 = ISNULL(@RRN, a.var64_37)
  --and substring(a.var64_35,1,16) =isnull(@CardNo,substring(a.var64_35,1,16))                                             
  AND
  (
  (
  (c.TransactionType IN ('SALE', 'REFUND', 'SETTLEMENT', 'LOYALTY_POINTS_REDEMPTION'))
  AND
  --( substring(a.var64_35,1,16) =isnull(@CardNo,substring(a.var64_35,1,16))  )                              
  (a.var64_02 = ISNULL(@CardNo, a.var64_02)
  )
  )
  OR ((c.TransactionType = 'MOTO')
  AND (a.var64_02 = ISNULL(@CardNo, a.var64_02)))

  )

  --and a. = isnull(@BatchNo,a.var64_60)                           

  AND
  (
  -------------For  BatchNo Check                           
  ------- For BatchNo  Check Is Not Null                                  
  ((a.var64_60 = @BatchNo)
  AND (@BatchNo IS NOT NULL))
  OR
  ----For BatchNo  Check Is  Null                                             
  ((@BatchNo IS NULL)
  AND (1 = 1)))


  AND a.var64_39 = '00'

  AND c.TransactionType IN ('SALE', 'MOTO', 'PUSH_QR_SALE', 'REFUND', 'SETTLEMENT', 'LOYALTY_POINTS_REDEMPTION')

  AND (
  -------------For Transactions Based On Order                              

  ------- For Is Order  1 Get Only Order Transactions                                     
  ((@IsOrder = 1)
  AND (a.OrderNo IS NOT NULL))
  ------- For Is Order 0 Get Other Transactions Than Order Transactions                                           
  OR
  ((@IsOrder = 0)
  AND (a.OrderNo IS NULL))
  OR
  ----For All Transactions                                              
  ((@IsOrder IS NULL)
  AND (1 = 1))
  )


  AND
  ----Start Of First And                                                
  (

  (

  @ReportTypeVar = 'TO_DATE'
  AND (
  ((CONVERT(varchar, a.TransactionDateTime, 106) IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ReportValues)
  )
  AND (@ReportValCount <> 0))
  OR ((CONVERT(varchar, a.TransactionDateTime, 106) = CONVERT(varchar, a.TransactionDateTime, 106))
  AND (@ReportValCount = 0))
  )

  )
  OR (

  @ReportTypeVar = 'WEEKDAY'
  AND (
  ((DATENAME(WEEKDAY, a.TransactionDateTime) IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ReportValues)
  )
  AND (@ReportValCount <> 0))
  OR ((DATENAME(WEEKDAY, a.TransactionDateTime) = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, a.TransactionDateTime))
  AND (@ReportValCount = 0))
  )
  )

  OR (
  @ReportTypeVar = 'MONTH'
  AND (
  ((DATENAME(MONTH, a.TransactionDateTime) IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ReportValues)
  )
  AND (@ReportValCount <> 0))
  OR ((DATENAME(MONTH, a.TransactionDateTime) = DATENAME(MONTH, a.TransactionDateTime))
  AND (@ReportValCount = 0))
  )
  )
  OR (
  @ReportTypeVar = 'QUARTER'
  AND (
  ((DATENAME(QUARTER, a.TransactionDateTime) IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ReportValues)
  )
  AND (@ReportValCount <> 0))
  OR ((DATENAME(QUARTER, a.TransactionDateTime) = DATENAME(QUARTER, a.TransactionDateTime))
  AND (@ReportValCount = 0))
  )
  )

  OR (
  @ReportTypeVar = 'DayOfMonth'
  AND (
  ((DATENAME(DAY, a.TransactionDateTime) IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ReportValues)
  )
  AND (@ReportValCount <> 0))
  OR ((DATENAME(DAY, a.TransactionDateTime) = DATENAME(DAY, a.TransactionDateTime))
  AND (@ReportValCount = 0))
  )
  )


  OR (

  @ReportTypeVar = 'TID_WISE'
  AND (
  ((a.var64_41 IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ReportValues)
  )
  AND (@ReportValCount <> 0))
  OR ((a.var64_41 = a.var64_41)
  AND (@ReportValCount = 0))
  )


  )

  OR (

  @ReportTypeVar = 'BATCHNO'
  AND (
  ((a.var64_60 IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ReportValues)
  )
  AND (@ReportValCount <> 0))
  OR ((1 = 1)
  AND (@ReportValCount = 0))
  )
  )
  OR (

  @ReportTypeVar = 'ASSOCIATION'
  AND (
  ((f.AssociationName IN (SELECT
    *
  FROM @ReportValues)
  )
  AND (@ReportValCount <> 0))
  OR ((f.AssociationName = f.AssociationName)
  AND (@ReportValCount = 0))
  )
  )
  )

  ----End Of First And                                                
  ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN j.ProductName IS NOT NULL THEN j.ProductCode
  END ASC,
  CASE
    WHEN j.ProductName IS NULL THEN a.TransactionDateTime
  END DESC, a.TransactionDateTime DESC) x
  ORDER BY x.sno ASC
  OFFSET ((@PageNo - 1) * @PageSize) ROWS
  FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;

**The result of execution plan is below.**
```

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads 55959, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 1158, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'TransactionRequestLog'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 2979, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'ProductHeirarchy'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'POSConditionCode'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 19452, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#B1653DF7'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19452, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'Association'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 19452, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'SettlementStatus'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 38905, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'TransactionStatus'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 38905, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'merchant'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 1750680, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#B2596230'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19453, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#A586BBB9'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19454, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'transactionresponselog'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 2110, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'GatewayTransactionType'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'POSEntryMode'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table **'CurrencyCode'**. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

All the tables except transactionresponselog and transactionrequestlog are master tables.

Comment: Please use pastetheplan.com, it is more handy and will provide much more info for us to debug. Also, what sql-server version are you using?

Comment: You can't even pretend to optimize this until you do some major formatting. How do you expect anybody to pick up 300 lines of this hot mess and make any sense of it?

Comment: You should also check out [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) before you continue the practice of aliases that are painful to work with. I actually tried to format this and gave up. It is just way too sloppy.

Comment: @SeanLange I had formatted the code, you can now view it..

Comment: The idea of formatting is to make it legible. Just lining everything up on the left does not help. I would estimate a solid 2 hours just to format this into something usable. That would be lining things up, removing all the extra spaces and stuff. Removing dozens of extra sets of parenthesis. That isn't touching on the challenges of the reason you posted in the first place. In a consulting situation I would estimate this to be around 20-40 hours to fix this up. And that is with the database in my hand. Doing this on a forum is just way too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a catch-all-query there are multiple articles about it, Gail Shaw has written several times about them like in her article [How to Confuse the SQL Server Query Optimizer](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/). There's no easy way to optimize this query. My suggestion is to use dynamic SQL to simplify the conditions. You also seem to have shared just a part of the whole procedure. The reason to believe that Dynamic SQL is the way to go and not recompiling every single time, is that the query is very complex and might timeout before being completely optimized.
Some of your column checks are written this way:

```
AND (
            -------------For  BatchNo Check                           
            ------- For BatchNo  Check Is Not Null                                  
            (
                (a.var64_60 = @BatchNo)
                AND (@BatchNo IS NOT NULL)
                )
            OR
            ----For BatchNo  Check Is  Null                                             
            (
                (@BatchNo IS NULL)
                AND (1 = 1)
                )
            )
```

Can be simplified to something like this:

```
AND (a.var64_60 = @BatchNo OR @BatchNo IS NULL)
```

This is similar to comparing with multiple values from a table-valued parameter.

```
AND (j.ProductCode IN ( SELECT * FROM @ProductCodes) OR @ProductCodesCount = 0)
```

Using dynamic code will also simplify the @ReportTypeVar conditions for the engine.

Be aware that even with dynamic SQL you need to be able to parametrize your query to prevent any kind of SQL injection.